# RegEx - double condition to find some string

Tags: regex

I'd like to find word `RADU3_` or `RADU3-` in a sentence that begins with `xlink:href=` and ends with `.svg`

How to do this?
I've tried following, but does not give the result I'm expecting.

> (?=\w*xlink:href=|\w*svg\b)|\bRADU3_|\bRADU3-

Just last line in example is good result (`RADU3_`)

ProductionGraphics\GP1**RADU3-**11_HeatingFurnaceF1.svg
PB:ExpressionText id="RADU3_FUEL GAS _SUM_EX" PBD:LinkUses
xlink:href="C:\ProcBookImport\MaintenanceGraphics\RADU3_AI.svg"

[Example...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQHNv.jpg)

Comment: Something like this `^(xlink:href).*(RADU3|RADU3-).*(\.svg")$` ? It depends of what do you mean by sentence. Should "xlink:href" be the begining of the line or can it be in anywhere ?

Comment: xlink:href is beginning of line, and .svg end of line. In this line I'd like to find string RADU3_ or RADU3- and replace with something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you want to use it but the below pattern finds the string. I put the RADU3 part in a group where I matches RADU3 followed by - or _ (`[_-]`)

```
(xlink:href=.*)(RADU3[_-]*)(.*\.svg)
```

---

*Edit, handle multiple occurences*

If a string might contain the pattern several times then use `?` to allow a group to repeat itself

```
(RADU3[_-]*?)(.*?\.svg?)
```

---

The above could be used in a replace expression like

```
\1someotherword\3
```

Where \2 is the second group that is replaced

Comment: Great! But this select whole string from beginning to the end. How to select only substring RADU3_ or RADU3- ? Thanks!

Comment: @Igor How do you use the regular expression? I have created a group, using parentheses, around the word so you should be able to access that group. See my example above.

Comment: @Igor if one of the answers here solves your question, please remember to mark it as the solution and upvote the answer(s) that worked for you. This helps the next person with the same problem :)

Comment: Link: https://regex101.com/r/woniEN/1   Shortly...how to find all RADU3[_-] which ends with .svg in text (svg file)? Problem is because this regex find just first string RADU3, not second or third in text. Regards, Igor

Comment: @Igor, I came up with a solution that I also tested successfully on the page you linked. See my edited section above.

Comment: Thanks Joakim, but if you look more carefully https://regex101.com/r/woniEN/2 in first selection is two .svg names. Only in first is selected RADU3_ and group 2 extends until second .svg  I need each of this to be selected, and later renamed (sorry for complication).

Comment: @Igor you are using the old pattern. Look more carefully for what I have changed,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want the word (substring) if it is in a specific context?

In your case, you can restart the regex midways if you want to have starting and ending conditions (multiple conditions) for a string, but at the same time only want to use these conditions as "if-statements" and not as part of the result.

The following uses this method, and utilizes restarts (`\K`) in order to only extract the substring you are looking for.

```
# The string has to start with "xlink:href="
xlink:href=
# Fetch everything up to our match, and the restart the regex
.*\K
# The strings we are looking for 
(RADU3[-_])
# String has to end with ".svg" 
(?=(.*\.svg))
```

If you want the entire string matching our rules you are looking for something like this:

```
#The string has to start with "xlink:href"
^(xlink:href=).*
# The strings we are looking for 
(RADU3[-_])
# String has to end with ".svg" 
(\w+\.svg)
#Get everything after .svg too
.*
```

If you only want the ending `"` after the .svg, you'd want to modify the last part where I just take everything after .svg

You can play around with what I have come up with at regex101 (no affiliation, just love their site): https://regex101.com/r/g0v07V/3/

Comment: I'd like to find all substrings (RADU3_ or RADU3-) in text where xlink:href is beginning of some line (string), and .svg end of line, and replace with something else. Thanks!

Comment: @Igor In that case I'd say the first one is the one you are after. Have you tried it to see if it works for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the string starts with `xlink:href=` and ends with `\.svg` you could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

Use 1 capturing group to make sure `xlink:href=` comes before RADU3 followed by an underscore or a hyphen. Then you could match it and in the replacement use that capturing group follwed by your replacement.

You could use a positive lookahead to assert that the string ends with `\.svg`

That will match:

```
^(xlink:href=.*)\bRADU3[_-](?=.*\.svg$)
```

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(xlink:href=.*)` Capturing group, match up until the last occurence of ..
- `\bRADU3[_-]` Word boundary to prevent matching part of a larger word. Match RADU3 followed by an underscore or hyphen
- `(?=.*\.svg$)` Positive lookahead to assert the string ends with `.svg`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ag84zd/1)

Comment: This selects quite a bunch of the string, and doesn't set the string OPs looking for into a group. So not really what OP is looking for ;) Kudos for explanations though! :)

Comment: @Squazz I think it does select what the OP is looking for. Look at the caputring group which captures `RADU3_`. This line is in the comments `xlink:href is beginning of line, and .svg end of line. In this line I'd like to find string RADU3_ or RADU3- and replace with something else.` If you look at the demo link you will see that that is what is being selected and replaced.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the replacement at the bottom. Sorry :) Actually, your solution is the fastest of the given solutions in order to substitute the string ;)

Comment: @Squazz No problem at all :)